# Update mysql value form checkbox value using AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have the following checkbox in a while loop and want to update the value in my mysql db, how can i do that? I hope that someone can help my? :)

I have added my AJAX code.

Checkbox/Whileloop

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $user ORDER BY page_order";

                 if ($row['status']==1) {
                                    $status = "checked";

                $users = $mysqli->query($sql);
                while($row = $users->fetch_assoc()){

              ?>
                    <tr  id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
                        <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['seconden'] ?> sec.</td>
                        <td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="status" data-toggle="toggle" value="<?php echo $row['status']; ?>" onchange="status()" <?php echo $status;?> record_id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> 
                                <a href="#edit<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Wijzig</a>
                                <a href="#del<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Verwijder</a>
                                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="view_page.php?user=<?php echo $user; ?>&page_order=<?php echo $row['page_order']; ?>" role="button">Bekijk</a>

                                <?php ?>




                            <?php include('button.php'); ?>

                            </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php 
            }
```

PHP Code:

```
if($_POST['value']==1){  //as used variable name "value" in ajax post data
        $query= mysql_query("UPDATE $user SET status = 1 WHERE id ='$_POST['record_id']'"); //query was incomplete and missing ";"
     }
     else{
          mysql_query("UPDATE $user SET status = 0 WHERE id ='$_POST['record_id']'");"
     }
```

AJAX:

```
 $("#status").onchange(function(){   
            var value1 = document.getElementById("status").value;
            var value2 = $('#status').data('record_id');

 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "status.php",
      data: "{'record_id':'" + value1+ "', 'value':'" + value2+ "'}")  
    }
  }
 );
```

Comment: What do you mean with "in a while loop" on a web page? Do you have several similar checkboxes? Then please show more context.

Comment: @AdrianW I have added my while loop

Comment: Do you have a table for every user?

Comment: you're also mixing / using different mysql apis here, why? you're also open to a serious SQL injection.

Comment: @niner Yes at this moment i use for every user  table

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i see it now, i'm learning. Can you help me?

Comment: What's the problem you're having? The code you posted looks like it should work.

Comment: You should update the second code to use mysqli instead of mysql, but otherwise it looks OK.

Comment: @Barmar The OP is using mysqli_ in one part and then mysql_ in the other. Probably why it's not working for them.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner They look like they're different scripts, one to create the form, another to process the submission.

Comment: @Barmar if their server supports the mysql_ api, sure. We don't know that though.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner We won't really know unless the OP comes back and explains what the problem is. I suspect his problem is actually in the Javascript that sends the AJAX, which he hasn't even shown.

Comment: @Barmar i have added my Javascript code

Answer (score 0):

The `data` option to `$.ajax` should not be JSON, it should be a URL-encoded string or an object (which jQuery will automatically convert to the URL-encoded string).

So use

```
data: { record_id: value1, value: value2 }
```

And even if it could be JSON, your formatting is wrong -- property names and string values have to be in double quotes, not single quotes. You should not try to create JSON by concatenating strings, use `JSON.stringify()` to ensure that it's encoded properly.

And your brackets are not properly balanced.

Another problem is that you have duplicate `id="status"`. IDs have to be unique. You should change it to `class="status"`, and then use `this` to refer to the checkbox that was clicked.

```js
$(".status").onchange(function() {
  var value1 = $(this).val();
  var value2 = $(this).data('record_id');

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "status.php",
    data: {
      record_id: value1,
      value: value2
    }
  })
});
```